# Operation between element in the same list of list generate from imported .dat files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a program that takes `.dat` files from directory one at a time, verifies some condition, and if verification is okay copies the files to another directory.

The code below shows how I import the files and create a list of lists. I'm having trouble with the verification step. I tried with a `for` loop but when set if condition, operation with elements in the list of lists seems impossible.

In particular I need the difference between consecutive elements `matrix[i][3]` and `matrix[i+1][3]` to be less than 5.

```
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, '*.dat')):
      with open(filename, 'r') as f:  

      matrix =[]
      data = f.readlines() 

      for raw_line in data:
        split_line1= raw_line.replace(":",";")
        split_line2= split_line1.replace("\n","")
        split_line3 = split_line2.strip().split(";")
        matrix.append(split_line3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome at Stack Overflow.

You did not provide a sample of your data files. After looking at your code, I assume your data looks like this:

```
9;9;7;5;0;9;5;8;4;2
9;1;1;5;1;3;4;1;8;7
2;8;4;5;5;2;1;4;6;4
6;4;1;5;5;8;1;4;6;1
0;1;0;5;7;1;7;4;1;9
4;9;6;5;3;2;6;2;9;6
8;0;6;0;8;9;3;1;6;6
```

A few general remarks:

- For parsing a csv file, use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module. It is easy to use and less error-prone than writing your own parser.
- If you do a lot of data-processing and matrix calculations, you want to have a look at the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/index.html) and [numpy](https://numpy.org/) libraries. Processing matrices line by line in plain Python is slower by some orders of magnitude.

I understand your description of the verification step as follows:

> A matrix matches if *all* consecutive elements 
>   `matrix[i][3]` and `matrix[i+1][3]` differ by less than 5.

My suggested code looks like this:

```py
import csv
from glob import glob
from pathlib import Path


def read_matrix(fn):
    with open(fn) as f:
        c = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";")
        m = [[float(c) for c in row] for row in c]
    return m


def verify_condition(matrix):
    col = 3
    pairs_of_consecutive_rows = zip(matrix[:-1], matrix[1:])
    for row_i, row_j in pairs_of_consecutive_rows:
        if abs(row_i[col] - row_j[col]) >= 5:
            return False
    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    folder_path = Path("../data")
    for filename in glob(str(folder_path / '*.dat')):
        print(f"processsing {filename}")
        matrix = read_matrix(filename)
        matches = verify_condition(matrix)
        if matches:
            print("match")
            # copy_file(filename, target_folder)
```

I am not going into detail about the function `read_matrix`. Just note that I convert the strings to float with the statement `float(c)` in order to be able to do numerical calculations later on.

I iterate over all consecutive rows by iterating over 'matrix[:-1]`and 'matrix[1:]` at the same time using `zip`. See the effect of `zip` in this example:

```
>>> list(zip("ABC", "XYZ"))
[('A', 'X'), ('B', 'Y'), ('C', 'Z')]
```

And the effect of the `[:-1]` and `[1:]` indices here:

```
>>> "ABC"[:-1], "ABC"[1:]
('AB', 'BC')
```

When `verify_condition` finds the first two consecutive rows that differ by at least 5, it returns false.

I am confident that this code should help you going on.

PS: I could not resist using the `pathlib` library because I really prefer to see code like `folder / subfolder / "filename.txt"` instead of `path.join(folder, subfolder, "filename.txt")` in my scripts.